# How can i get an audio inputStream from youtube Url

Tags: java, kotlin, youtube

I want to know how can i get an audio from youtube url

I was playing a music with Jlayer and succeed to play .mp3 file and audioUrl but i can't play an audio with youtubeUrl

I tried same as audioUrl

```
URL url = New URL(youtubeURL);

url.openConnection().openStream();
```

Comment: Please do not develop an illegal Youtube2Mp3 converter or Downloader. ;) You can google how this is done.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am not making a downloader i just want to stream an audio